# Parsing date and time from formatted date

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I have a date in the following format:

```
Wed Jul 17 2013 13:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Can anyone tell me how to parse the date

```
Wed Jul 17 2013
```

and time out of this without using string functions

```
1:00pm
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse please see this link hope this helpfull to you

Comment: Looks like a toString output of a date object. Can you access the object itself? Where are you getting this input from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: _"without using string functions"_ - Why? Isn't that pretty much what "parsing" is all about? Especially when the date is already in exactly the format you need, and the time just needs a minor tweak to switch to am/pm format. (To do it _without_ string functions you'd have to convert it to a `Date` and then get out the individual pieces and assemble them back into the format you want...)

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways is to make sure your LOCALES are set properly, which allows you to do something like this:

```
var myStrDate = 'Wed Jul 17 2013 13:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)';
var myDate = Date.parse(myStrDate);
var myDateOnly = myDate.toLocaleDateString();
var myTimeOnly = myDate.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Here's a great place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `Date` object with the date string, combined with additional functions to get the required output. `dayname`() returns the dayname, `monthname`() returns the three-letter month name.

I've used `console.info()` for outputting results - `alert()` can be used as an alternative if appropriate.

```
function dayname(d)
{
  var names = [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri","Sat" ];
  return names[d.getDay()];
}
function monthname(d)
{
    var names = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    return names[d.getMonth()];
}

// construct new date object passing date string as parameter  
var d = new Date("Wed Jul 17 2013 13:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)");
console.info(dayname(d) + ' ' + monthname(d) + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear());
```

For the time, this `gettime`() function checks the hour to output am or pm correctly, and for correct formatting-:

```
function gettime(d)
{
    var ampm = "am";
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    if (hour >= 12)
    {
        hour = hour - 12;
        ampm = "pm";
    }
    if (hours < 10)
        hours = "0" + hours;
    if (mins < 10)
        mins = "0" + mins;
    return hour + ":" + mins + ampm;
}
console.info(gettime(d));
```

Comment: But this formats the current date. OP said they already have a specific date in a specific format...

Comment: updated. The date object is now created using the date string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ms = Date.parse(new Date("Wed Jul 17 2013 13:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
var curr_date = ms.getDate();
var curr_month = ms.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = ms.getFullYear();
var hours = ms.getHours();
var mins = ms.getMinutes();
suf = (hours >= 12)? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year + "  " + hours + ":" + min + " " + suffix);
```

Also try using [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/), you can format dateTime as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here great reference to learn date functions in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date